# Updating an HTML list using Js

Tags: javascript, html, listview

So I have a js game like scrabble. Now when the user makes a new word, I would like the word to be added to a list that is displayed in a div on my page.
The issue is I quite don't understand, how I could keep my old word created and insert a new word with new formatting and everything in a list form.

I know there is a list tag --

```
<ul>
     <li>apple</li>
     <li>ball</li>
</ul>
```

but what I can't really figure out is how do I use java script to enter the word as a new list entry.

I have used js to display the word created by the following syntax

```
document.getElementById('currentword').innerHTML = word;
```

where word is the variable that holds the current word created and *currentword* is the div id. but how do I use this kind of syntax for a list?
Please help!

Thanks

EDIT: I would also like the last entry to the list as the first item on my list. Seems like the list populates itself but the latest entry gets hidden and the list doesn't really auto scroll down as the items are added.
PS: Also incase someone knows how I could replace the tacky scroll bar option generated by CSS to a custom scroll bar. It would be great if you could point me in the correct direction!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a list:

```
<ul id="theList" >
     <li>apple</li>
     <li>ball</li>
</ul>
```

you could add an `<li>` like this (assuming that the variable `word` contains the word you want to add):

```
document.getElementById('theList').innerHTML += ('<li>'+word+'</li>');
```

There are other ways too, but this one is probably the simplest.

Comment: Thanks... btw if I want to introduce CSS effects on this, replacing the id with with class would help and calling the style would work right?

Comment: If you replace id with class, then `getElementById()` won't find the `ul` element any more.  There is a [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/document.getelementsbyclassname), but it works slightly differently.  Of course, `id` and `class` can exist together on the same tag (like this: `<ul id="theList" class="someClass">`).  That will let you apply css rules by class, and still use `getElementById()` to retrieve the element from javascript.  If you're doing advanced effects or anmimation, It might be easier to try a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Thanks lee. actually I am using mootools as my framework so I would not like the inclusion of another fw. :) But I have already created classes of all the effects I would like using CSS3 so I was just wondering, the way I render animation to div's on the dom, if it would be possible to do the same. Another issue I have mentioned is I would like the last entry to the list as the first item on the list. It would be great if you could sort that out! Thanks... :)

Comment: Performance of this will suck once the list gets long. You keep redrawing all of those elements instead of just adding one.

Comment: @epascarello: yes, as I said: "There are other ways, but this one is probably the simplest".  Simplest, not best performing.

Answer (score 3):

I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for dom manipulation and would recommend the same for you, it adds a lot of readability and tons of neat (x-browser friendly) functionality.

For example... the [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) api call would do the job if you were using jQuery.

```
<ul id="words">
 <li>Some Word</li>
 <li>Another Word</li>
</ul>

$("#words").append("<li>" + yourNewWord + "</li>");
```

Or with straight javascript...

```
document.getElementById('words').innerHTML += '<li>' + yourNewWord + '</li>';
```

**EDIT:**
I believe in motools the equivalent to .append is [.grab](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3agrab)

Comment: I am actually using mootools, would not like to introduce another library... but thanks for ur help :)

Comment: Any idea how to get rid of the bullets for certain entries while leave it for the rest?

Comment: Just one more question... How do I get the latest list entry to go on top of the list? Right now they are getting appended to the bottom of the list! Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = "new text";
document.getElementById("TheULsId").appendChild(li);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
 <li>apple</li>
 <li>ball</li>
</ul>
```

then,

```
var newListItem = $('<li></li>').html("myNewWord");

$("ul").append(newListItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to the exact solution of my question, I figured out the rest from mootools docs :)

This fiddle demonstrated most of it.. http://jsfiddle.net/WngSS/1/

As for the scroll bar goes, well to customize ur own scrollbar you just use css effects.